# Remove link from active navbar page in Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to remove the link from a item from navbar in TW Bootstrap 3.

```
<li class="active">
    <a href="#1">Link 1 (active) - This must to be a text, not a link</a>
</li>
```

It seems that the styles are applied to `a` tag from navbar.
How can I remove the link from the active navbar item keeping same style?

---

I know that this can be hacked easy with some js:

```
on click --> return false;
```

and css:

```
a:hover { cursor: default; }
```

But I would not do this if this is possible with build-in classes in Bootstrap 3.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ssd5L/)

Comment: use bootstrap class 'disabled'

Comment: Simply add your own stylesheet after BS to get rid of the the effect. Simply over-write.

Comment: @SridharR `disabled` is not the best idea. It makes the text unselectable and gray.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Yes, the question is which way is the most efficient one?

Comment: the best way is write specific class in css and put

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way would be using `css`. You can simply add your new rule *after* the link to your BS css file. So, this would be the best way:

```
a:hover { cursor: default; }
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ssd5L/2/)

Comment: And when clicking...? I need that `return false;` Am I right?

Comment: @Johnツ I think so. Try it out and see. The problem with css and javascript is that it changes with every passing moment, so you can't say something will work until it does.

Comment: I chose this way. `return false` + `cursor: default`.

Comment: @Johnツ Awesome it worked out. I had to do something similar to this, and boy it was a pain because I had to get it to work on different browsers! :P Thats why I could never be sure if it would work you see, all I knew that you needed to add the CSS after bs for the cascading effect.